# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property HttpContext.Server'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm really confuse why it doesn't work. I searched but I didn't find anything.

I'm writing ASP.NET WebApi and I have got this method in my controller

```
private void test()
{    
    string pathApp = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/MyFirstProject-db5185b5746d.p12");
}
```

Why am I getting this error? What's wrong with this?

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property HttpContext.Server'

or if you know how to get path to

> AppData/MyFirstProject-db5185b5746d.p12

another way you can post it here.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you understand the error message at all? It's not clear which part you don't understand at the moment. Note that `HttpContext.Server` is an instance property. Perhaps you want `HttpContext.Current.Server`?

Comment: Man thanks it helped me, but I still don't know why everybody post in other questions that HttpContext.Server should be used.

Comment: You should look at the context of those answers - I suspect they're used when there's a property `HttpContext` which returns the current `HttpContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error-message says `Server` is not static. This means the property belongs to an object and not to a class. Create an object of HttpContext or get it from somewhere and you can access the `Server`-Property:

```
private void test()  
{    
    HttpContext context = new HttpContext(); //or getX, maybe you need parameters
    string pathApp = context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/MyFirstProject-db5185b5746d.p12");  
}
```